# Redirecionamento DNS - Problema Uso serviço da AWS

Tags: amazon-aws, dns

Como configurar meu servidor DNS para redirecionar sempre pegadadelixo.com.br para www.pegadadelixo.com.br?

Comment: Rodrigo já tenho um código para isto www.pegadadelixo.com.br.
CNAME
ghs.google.com (não consigo criar dois com o mesmo nome:www)

Comment: E por que você está apontando o www pro google em vez de apontar pra raiz?

Answer (score 3):

Com .htacess também você pode ajustar isso:

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Qual a utilidade adicional deste código? Basta adicioná-lo após o <head>?

Comment: Não, é o arquivo .htacess que é criado e salvo no mesmo diretório de seu projeto. Veja aqui mais sobre ele: http://www.mundoseo.com.br/seo/htaccess-tudo-o-que-voce-precisa-saber-e-mais-um-pouco/

Answer (score 1):

Basta configurar um registro do tipo `CNAME`:

```
dominio.com   CNAME   www.dominio.com   300
```

(300 é o TTL, em segundos, daquele registro.)

Comment: Como é que vc faz CNAME da raiz? Tá estranho isso. O normal é o inverso (apontar o www para o sem www).

Answer (score 1):

Se você já estiver usando o Route 53, poderá usar o apelido proprietário "record" para resolver esse problema. Com o DNS padrão, você não pode fazer isso e é necessário que um site envie um redirecionamento 301. Obviamente, você ainda precisa enviar os redirecionamentos 301 ou lidar com o fato de que algumas solicitações serão recebidas sem o www.

Provavelmente, a maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é configurar um bucket S3 com o nome do domínio e configurar as propriedades do bucket para redirecionar de example.com para www.example.com e, em seguida, no Route 53, criar um alias para o o nome de domínio que aponta para esse bucket S3.

**Para melhorar a resposta, segue os passo para funcionar:**

- Configure o bucket - não importa qual seja o nome e deve permitir o público.
- No bucket, clique em propriedades e clique em hospedagem estática de sites. 
  Clique em redirecionar todas as solicitações para outro nome de host e digite o site para o qual você deseja que o tráfego vá.
- Copie o terminal do nome do bloco e vá para a zona hospedada no console do Route53 e adicione um CNAME com Alias ​​No ao URL do qual você precisa ser redirecionado e cole o terminal como seu valor.

Answer (score 0):

Como o DNS não permite CNAME para a raíz da zona (sem www.), considere as seguintes alternativas:

- Usar uma distribuição do CloudFront com múltiplos CNAMES: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html
- Criar um ALIAS apontando diretamente para seu ELB, S3 Static Website ou distribuição do CloudFront.
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html
- Se estiver armazenado no S3, usar as regras de redirecionamento: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax

Comment: _"o DNS não permite CNAME para a raíz da zona"_ Isso é verdade, mas no caso do autor da pergunta seria o contrário, o `www` que será o CNAME, não? `www CNAME pegadadelixo.com.br.` me parece trivial.

Comment: Precisamente eu tive que usar o CloudFront.